# Как у spinbox увеличить размер стрелок

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Не нашел сразу ответ в интернете. 
Использую тачьскрин и размер стрелок spinbox не позволяет пальцем изменить значение числа. Как можно увеличить размер стрелок. Qt 4.7.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ поправит отображение всех элементов в программе - [Qt Style Sheets](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html). Например:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    a.setStyleSheet(
                "QSpinBox::up-button   { width: 64px; height: 64px; } \n"
                "QSpinBox::down-button { width: 64px; height: 64px; } \n"
                "QSpinBox              { height: 128px; } \n"
                );

    // test
    QSpinBox w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Но, если где-то в программе, сделаны предположения о размерах элементов, то диалоговые окна могут "поплыть". Тогда следует поправлять стиль для элементов по отдельности.